# Reputation with migrated questions

Tags: support, reputation, migration

This has been asked before [on the SO meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/do-migrated-questions-migrate-reputation-and-badges) but something still is not clear to me.

I noticed a nice question by Simon has been migrated.

[Is there a Mathematica API for the functions.wolfram site?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/911/121)

This shows thirteen votes, yet viewing Simon's profile I do not see the corresponding reputation.  Is this going to be adjusted in a future recalculation, or are his reputation points vaporized?

Comment: @R.M that doesn't sound right; you say "has to be decided" but are you sure that is within the community's control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's there, you just have to look down at May 31, 2011 when the question was asked. Also, he answered his own question, which makes accounting by hand a little trickier. That's the big problem with these older questions, their rep is added in, but prior to the start of the current site.

Comment: So it is!  I *did* look for that but somehow I missed it (or perhaps it updated after I looked but I doubt it).